# WPF Keeping Images in Memory

Tags: wpf, memory-leaks

My WPF UI is keeping all of the images I use in memory. Below is the relevant retention graph. Using the ANTS Memory Profiler 8.7, I have established that none of my code is holding onto any these objects. I have written code so that multiple request for the same image create only one image, but that leaves me with the problem that there are enough images within my application to crash it when they are all loaded simultaneously. I turned off this code when I ran this memory profile. I need to flush these images. I have even resorted to manually calling `GC.Collect` which did not reduce the memory used. Something is holding these images and it is not my code.

[image]

Here is the code for how I expose the `BitmapImage` to then be bound to `Image.Source`. This does not contain my image-to-path dictionary caching service that is now turned off.

```
public BitmapImage Image
{
    get 
    {
        var image = new BitmapImage();
        image.BeginInit();
        image.UriSource = a_url;
        image.CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.IgnoreImageCache;
        image.EndInit();
        image.Freeze();

        return image;
    }
}

// The XAML
<Image Source="{Binding Image, Mode=OneWay}"/>
```

**NOT A DUPLICATE**
I have determined that the `BitmapImage` is being held on to and have explicitly invoked `GC.Collect` which did nothing. The problem is not the GC. I also always `Freeze` my `BitmapImage` objects when I create them in code. This is not my first time around.

Comment: show the code for how you are loading (and disposing) the images

Comment: Thanks for giving me the scarlet 'D' even though this is not a direct duplicate. I guess I'll try another forum.

Comment: You're using an open source library called "WPF Animated GIF"?

Comment: @GlenThomas, Not hear with these images, but I am using it elsewhere.

Comment: @ErnodeWeerd, I've read that entire post. I'm not using streams at all. Are you suggesting that I do?

Comment: Try removing any use of WPF Animated GIF library and then see if you can still reproduce the memory leak.

Comment: Easier said than done. That will take a while.

Comment: You have used it in lots of places? Can you show an example of how you use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see from the object graph that you have a class called `ImageAnimationController`, which is holding a reference to the Image control that uses your BitmapImage as its source by a `DependencyPropertyDescriptor`. The `ImageAnimationController` uses the `DependencyPropertyDescriptor` to subscribe to change notifications of the `Image` control's `Source` `DependencyProperty`. When the `ImageAnimationController` class is disposed it will unsubscribe from the `DependencyPropertyDescriptor` notifications.

It looks like this `ImageAnimationController` class is a component of an open source library called *WPF Animated GIF*. I can't see how you are using this library as you have not included the source, but I imagine that somewhere you have either something like this:

```
ImageBehavior.SetAnimatedSource(img, image);
```

Or this:

```
<Image gif:ImageBehavior.AnimatedSource="{Binding Image}" />
```

I am not familiar with this library or your code, but I imagine that you will need to ensure that this attached behaviour is correctly detached and disposed of.

Comment: That was it! Thank you. I switched over to XamlAnimatedGif, and now GC is collecting them again. Here is the new library (https://github.com/thomaslevesque/XamlAnimatedGif) It works very much like the original but works better with memory.